# Sublime Text Nested Bracket Has Extra Tab Auto Indentation

Tags: sublimetext3

When adding a newline inside a function call the closing bracket is always an extra tab over, is there a setting or a configuration file somewhere I can modify to remove that extra tab?

[image: Gif of the extra tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this by:

1. Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) if you don't already have it installed
2. Open the Command Palette
3. Type `PRV: O` and select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
4. Select `JavaScript`
5. Select `JavaScript Indent.tmPreferences`
6. at the bottom of the file, before `</dict>`, add:

   ```
   <key>indentParens</key>
   <false />
   ```
7. Save it

ST will no longer indent the next line when you type <kbd>Enter</kbd> in between the square brackets on JavaScript lines like `spawn('div', this.view, {}, [])`

Comment: Your answer was perfect, that does exactly what I asked for, I wish I could treat the result like a typical indentation block (so the ending brace doesn't indent but content does), if you have any hints I'd appreciate it, but the main question is answered.