# Sublime Text 3 auto indents my } else { line

Tags: c#, sublimetext3, auto-indent

In Sublime Text 3 and C#, I am struggling with the auto indentation. It somehow assumes that I want a closing bracket with "else" indented, which I do not. As soon as I enter the first letter of "else", it indents the line. I haven't found out how to turn this off.

[image]

Comment: What if you continue typing another `{` at the end?

Comment: Go on typing, see what happens. Pretty sure, it's just a temporary glitch.

Comment: It is more readable to obey the convention for if-else. I suggest you to write else in a new line. You can see some conventions here.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but it doesn't unindent even when I finish the line. When I write else in a new line, it works, but I would prefer to have it in one line.
If it's a bug, it is at least good to know that this is not intended.

Comment: I think this post can help you here (although it is not exactly the same, but quite close). Short story: you can configure ST behaviour. If this helps, let us know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473508/sublime-text-nested-bracket-has-extra-tab-auto-indentation